# Linear algebra, sub spaces, dimension, span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the subspaces $A=span\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,1,-1)\}$ and $B=span\{(1,0,-1,0),(0,1,0,-1)\}$ of $\mathbb{F}^4$.

A) what are the dimensions of these subspaces?
The dimension of both subspaces is $2$.

B) show that $A+B\le \{(X1,X2,X3,X4)\in \mathbb{F}^4\ |\  X1+X2+X3+X4=0\}$.

I have no idea where to start on this question, we are not allowed to use matrices to show span etc.

But I know through a matrix reduction that the vectors are linearly dependent, and when the fourth one is removed they become independent. Don't know if this helps.

C) describe $A\cap B$. What is its dimension? 
It's asking for the elements which lie in both $A$ and $B$. I have managed to work out that this is more than the zero element. I am convinced it is a one dimensional space, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$A=span\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,1,-1)=\{a(1,-1,0,0)+b(0,0,1,-1): a,b \in \Bbb{F}\}=\{(a,-a,b,-b) : a,b \in \Bbb{F}\}$

and similarly $B=\{(c,d,-c,-d): c,d \in \Bbb{F}\}$.

Now $A+B=\{(a+c,d-a,b-c,-b-d)\}\le \{(X1,X2,X3,X4)\in \mathbb{F}^4\ |\  X1+X2+X3+X4=0\}$

---

Now  to find $A \cap B$, pick any element of $A$ ,lets say, $(x,-x,y,-y)$, now to be in $B$, we further need, $x=-y$, so $A\cap B=\{(x,-x,-x,x)=x(1,-1,-1,1): x\in \Bbb{F}\}$, thus dimension is clearly one.

Comment: what does (a+c,d-a,b-c,-b-d) actually mean? Like it is not in the same for as X1+X2+X3+X4=0 which describes a plane. What does the first describe?

Answer (score 0):

Note that  dimension of {(X1,X2,X3,X4) $\in$ $\Bbb{F^4}$ | X1+X2+X3+X4=0} is $4-1=3$.

So dimension of $A+B$$\leq3$.
Now dim(A+B)=dimA+dim B-dim(A$\cap$B).

Now $2\geq$dim(A$\cap$B)=dimA+dim B-dim(A+B)$\geq$$2+2-3=1$.But dim(A$\cap$B) can't be two as they are not same subspace.So dim(A$\cap$B)=1.
This implies $dim(A+B)=2+2-1=3$ ,from the same formula.

Comment: How do you know that the dimension of X1+X2+X3+X4=0 is 4-1?

Comment: $F^4$ is spanned by four linearly independent vector.But in {(X1,X2,X3,X4) ∈ F4 | X1+X2+X3+X4=0} basis elements satisfy a relation ,that means you can write one of the vector in basis in terms of three other basis element.So dim will be one less.

Comment: Why not two less? Why does it have to be strictly one less,

Comment: Also do you have any help for part b? I still don't understand